# How to define jquery selector valid id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using following jquery selector by id

```
$("#rs_0.01").val();
```

So my small question is: this valid or not ?
As it's not working in my case.

Comment: `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: `$("[id='rs_0.01']").val();` or `$("#rs_0\\.01").val();`

Comment: $("[id='rs_0.01']").val(); is good for me. @PranavCBalan Please post it as answer.
Other solutions may work. But i am using loop for displaying currency denominations my loop contains 1,2,5,10,etc values. So mentioned solution is working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [documentation of jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS character escape sequences for identifiers.

---

So you can use

```
$("#rs_0\\.01").val();
```

or use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) instead

```
$("[id='rs_0.01']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:
You need to escape special chars:

```
$("#rs_0\\.01").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you got few ways to retrieve value of a textbox by using id selector with the same name which you have specified in the question..

One way is by doing like this:

```
$("[id='rs_0.01']").val();
```

or you can use the escape sequence inbetween the selector name like this:

```
$("#rs_0\\.01").val();
```